# How to escape semicolon in ruby rxml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm using Ruby On Rails' RXML to create a sitemap feed for Google.

Google requires that [images are marked up with the image name space](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=6080646&rd=1), requiring an element that has a semicolon in it like this:

```
<image:image>
  <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> 
</image:image>
```

If I use

```
xml.image:loc => "something"
```

I get

```
<image:image>
  <image loc="something"/>
</image:image>
```

If I use

```
xml.image:loc("something")
```

I get

```
    compile error
/home/vagrant/website/app/views/feeds/sitemap.rxml:36: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting kEND
                                            xml.image:loc("something")
```

If I try this

```
xml.image:loc do
  puts  "something"
end
```

I get this

```
<image:image>
  <image:loc>
  </image:loc>
</image:image>
```

Comment: I don't have enough permission to add RXML as a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rxml templates are in fact [builder](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/blob/master/README.md)

If the first argument to the magic tag method is a symbol, then that makes builder use the method name as the namespace and the symbol as the tag name. For example

```
xml.image(:loc, "something")
```

Will produce

```
<image:loc>something</image:loc>
```

It's the sane when passing a block too:

```
xml.image(:image) do |xml|
  xml.image(:loc, "http://example.com")
end
```